# Nature of the series $\sum _{n=1}^\infty (\sin n)^n $ , $\sum _{n=1}^\infty (\cos n)^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do we discuss the convergence of the following series

i)$\sum _{n=1}^\infty (\sin n)^n $

ii)$\sum _{n=1}^\infty (\cos n)^n $

Comment: They both diverge, as the terms don't go to zero.

Comment: Can you make a multiple of $\pi $ by running through the natural numbers (mod $2\pi$)?

Comment: (Integer multiple)

Comment: @mixedmath: I'm sure you're right, but it's not obvious!

Answer (score 6):

> HINT : Show that there exists a sequence of integers $(p_n)$ and  a sequence of integers $(q_n)$ such that $|\pi-\frac{p_n}{q_n}|<\frac{1}{q_n^2}$ for ii)
>
> And, for i) Show that there exists a sequence of integers $(p_n)$ and  a sequence of integers $(q_n)$ chosen so that all the terms of ${q_n}$ are odd, such that $|\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}|<\frac{1}{q_n^2}$

Then, $$\vert \cos(p_n)\vert=\vert \cos(\pi q_n-p_n)\vert>\cos(\frac{1}{q_n})=1-2\sin^2(\frac{1}{2q_n})>1-\frac{1}{2q_n^2}$$
and, $$\vert \cos(p_n)\vert^{p_n}>\bigr(1-\frac{1}{2q_n^2}\bigl)^{p_n}> 1-\frac{p_n}{2q_n^2} $$

Therefore, the sequence $\{(cos(p_n))^{p_n}\}$and $\{ \cos(n)^n\}$ doesn't converge to $0$. It follows that ii) diverge.

For i) It's the same sketch so I leave it to you.